# How to retrieve single quote words form sentence in javascript?

Tags: javascript

```js
var str = `Then I should 'create' 'adhoc payments' on '01' working day of pay period '04' of 'Current' Fiscal`
var spilitArr = str.split(" ");
var filterArr = spilitArr.filter(e=>e.includes("'"));

// s.match(/'([^']+)'/)[1];
console.log(spilitArr, 'spilitArr')
console.log(filterArr, 'filterArr')

console.log(`expected array:' , ['create' 'adhoc payments', '01', '04', 'Current']`)
```

Tried multiple ways, can any one help me.

Answer (score 4):

You were kind of barking up the right tree with your RegExp attempt; a pattern like `/(?<=\W').+?(?='\W)/g` will probably get you to where you need to be to meet your requirement:

```js
var str = `Then I should 'create' 'adhoc payments' on '01' working day of pay period '04' of 'Current' Fiscal`
const pattern = /(?<=\W').+?(?='\W)/g;
const matches = str.match(pattern);
console.log(matches);
```

Comment: Hi @esqew, could you kindly explain what does "word" means in the regex?

Comment: @h-sifat It's a [named capturing group](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Groups_and_Ranges), which makes it easier to extract the part of the match you're really interested in. I accidentally left in while I was working with the solution a bit - I've since edited it out.

Comment: This won't work with "It's a good 'word'".

Comment: @itsmygit That's true, English contractions will in fact cause this to not function as intended. Let me re-work it a bit.

Comment: @esqew you are almost right but I don't like these kinds of fixes.

Comment: @itsmygit I think the new pattern I've come up with is pretty robust, I'd be interested to hear if you have any further feedback.

Comment: I'm writing an answer now. Will post it soon.

Comment: It is good answer, and on more `str.match(pattern)` was enough instead of `[...str.match(pattern)]`

Comment: @RinshanKolayil Thanks, you're right! Something left over from an earlier iteration of this solution when I was using this in a slightly different way.

Comment: @esqew this final version of your answer is great. Well done.

Comment: this code also remove the white spaces after the open single quotes and before the close single quotes if the spaces more than one. so the words stored in the array are not the same as the words in single quotes. it would be a problem if every white space inside a single quote had a specific purpose.

Comment: @HannaRose I'm not following your comment here - if you add an additional whitespace, say, between the words `adhoc` and `payments` in `str` above, the match still returns with both whitespaces intact. Can you elaborate a bit?

Comment: I understand that you only provide solutions according to the request of the problem. I'm not forcing, just pointing out something that has the potential to become a problem later. the purpose of all of us being here is to collaborate to find the best solution.

Comment: `He said'that' I should 'create' 'adhoc payments' on '01' working day of pay period '04' of 'Current' Fiscal` => ["create","adhoc payments","01","04","Current"]
your code giving a wrong answer for this str. its skip the word 'that'

Comment: @HannaRose This RegExp doesn't solve for data quality issues where the input string has lexical/syntactical issues. If the OP is looking for something that solves for that then I would encourage them to make an edit to their original question to indicate as such; otherwise it seems to me that this issue is more arbitrarily manufactured than anything else.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var str = `Then I should 'create' 'adhoc payments' on '01' working day of pay period '04' of 'Current' Fiscal`;
let res = [];

for( let a=0; a<str.length; a++ ){
  const sqOpen = str.indexOf("'", a);
  const sqClose =( sqOpen !== -1 )? str.indexOf("'", sqOpen+1):-1;
  if( sqClose !== -1 ){
    a = sqClose + 1;
    res.push( str.slice(sqOpen+1, sqClose ) );
  }else{
    break;
  }
}
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use this code

```
var result = [];
while(str.indexOf("'") > -1)
{
    str = str.substr(str.indexOf("'") + 1);
    result.push(str.substr(0, str.indexOf("'")));
    str = str.substr(str.indexOf("'") + 1);
}
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var str = `Then I should 'create' 'adhoc payments' on '01' working day of pay period '04' of 'Current' Fiscal`
const pattern = /'(.*?)'/g;
const matches = str.match(pattern).map(e => e.substring(1,e.length-1))
console.log(matches);
```